# Should third-party static libraries be included as an item in VC++ 2010 project?

Tags: visual-c++

I use third party static library (provided as a .LIB file without source code) in my project. For linking purposes it is enough to add it via "Properties/Linker/Input->Additional Dependencies"

This library is not used in any other project in the solution.

I wonder if I should add it as an item to project file itself. The advantages that I see: it will be immediately obvious that this project uses it and one wouldn't have to add it to version control system manually (anything that is a part of the project/solution is added automatically if you use something like AnkSVN).

Answer (score 0):

The project in VCS must be buildable. It is impossible without the lib. So you should add it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. Do you mean that I should add it to the project? Or to VCS? It goes without saying that it should be in VCS, whether one has to put it there manually or via Visual Studio integration if it is part of the project.

Comment: In that case it doesn't matter much. I would add it to the project. You just have to make sure it checkouts where the vcproj expects it. So better if it is part of the project and with relative path